# How to insert elements into an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array consisting of unknown elements:

```
myary = [100, "hello", 20, 40, "hi"]
```

I want to put integer `10` after each element to make it into this:

```
myary = [100, 10, "hello", 10, 20, 10, 40, 10, "hi", 10]
```

Is there a way or a method to do it?

Another problem is that I need to add integer `10` before a string `"hello"`.

```
myary = [100, 10,"hello", 20, 40, "hi"]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the length? Surely you can just do `myary.size`, right? Did you mean the size varies, i.e., it is different all the time?

Comment: `myary.map { |i| i == 'hello' ? i: [i, 10] }.flatten`

Comment: @meagar In that 'hello' case he wants to add 10 *before* the 'hello' element and otherwise not insert anything, so that should be `i == 'hello' ? [10, i] : i`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I read that backwards, but sure. Question should be closed as too broad regardless.

Comment: Thanks all,
Yevgeniy Anfilofyev, I have tried "insert" method and it's not nice for my case, and I don't know about flat_map method yet.
Daniel Knippers, I don't know the length because the array is not predictable, I try to work in a program that my senior give me, the program give me an array that I can't see the length, and my senior forbid me to use .size or .length method(but this not the real problem, and sorry for not mention this in my question above).
Well the real problem is I must insert that 10 integer in before specific data in the array.
    flat_map 
is what I want, thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
myary = [100, "hello", 20, 40, "hi"]
myary.flat_map { |i| [i, 10] }
# => [100, 10, "hello", 10, 20, 10, 40, 10, "hi", 10] 
myary.flat_map { |i| i == 'hello' ? [10, i] : i }
# => [100, 10,"hello", 20, 40, "hi"]
```

Read [`#flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) method.

Comment: Great answer, as always!

Comment: Alternative ways: `myary.zip([10].cycle).flatten` and `myary.inject([]) {|m,e| e=='hello' ? m.push(10,e): m << e}` but would prefer also flat_map in this case.

Comment: @DavidUnric `myary.zip([10].cycle) == myary.product([10])`